# How do I determine the transfer function of a plant?

Tags: matlab, control-theory, estimation, transfer-theory

I sitting here with a system which I have to determine the transfer function. 
The unit receives a velocity and position, and move towards that position with the given velocity.  What kind of test would one perform for determining the transfer function...

I know MATLAB provides a method. The problem though I am a bit confused on what kind of test it should perform, and how I should use Matlab to determining the transfer function?

The unit which is being used is a Flir PTU D48E

Answer (score 1):

For real processes the standard way to determine the transfer function of the plant is to implement *system identification* methods using experimental data of the plant. This procedure would yield the state space representation of the system (A,B, C, D matrices):
$\dot{x} = Ax + Bu$
$y = Cx + Du$

Then using the *tf* command one can derive the transfer function of the plant.

Another way of deriving the transfer function is by using *reverse Bode plots*.

Links on the methods are provided below:

http://www.mathworks.com/products/sysid/?refresh=true

http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/tf.html

http://vimeo.com/64611091

Comment: What if i am not seeking a state space model but just a normal model of a stepper motor.

Comment: What do you mean 'normal' ?

Comment: Not a state stave model.. 
The system can also be changed to only take vel.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to have a transfer function based on your the plant you have. This should be seen as a system identification problem. You need to select a model, which normally can be linear, and try to find the model's parameters. MATLAB has tools for that.